# JPA: TypedQuery sometimes returns null instead of NoResultException

Tags: jpa, hql, jpa-2.0

Usually I work with NoResultException to return an "empty" object, e.g. an empty error list or new BigInteger("0"), if I get no results from a TypedQuery. Now it turned out that this sometimes doesn't work. Suddenly getSingleResult() returns null instead of causing a NoResultException, and I don't understand why. Look this example:

```
public BigInteger pointsSumByAccountId(long accountId)
{
    try
    {
        TypedQuery<BigInteger> pointsQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery(Points.SumByAccountId, BigInteger.class);
        pointsQuery.setParameter(Points.AccountIdParameter, accountId);

        return pointsQuery.getSingleResult();
    }
    catch (NoResultException e)
    {
        return new BigInteger("0");
    }
}
```

The important part of the Entity...

```
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "Points.sumByAccountId", query = "select sum(p.value) from Points p where p.validFrom <= current_timestamp() and p.validThru >= current_timestamp() and p.account.id = :accountId")})
public class Points
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -15545239875670390L;

    public static final String SumByAccountId = Points.class.getSimpleName() + ".sumByAccountId";
    public static final String AccountIdParameter = "accountId";
.
.
.
```

If I use an accountId which causes no results, I get null instead of NoResultException. Any ideas why this is so? Even Javadoc of TypedQuery says that it has to return NoResultException:

```
/**
 * Execute a SELECT query that returns a single result.
 *
 * @return the result
 *
 * @throws NoResultException if there is no result
 * @throws NonUniqueResultException if more than one result
 * @throws IllegalStateException if called for a Java
 * Persistence query language UPDATE or DELETE statement
 * @throws QueryTimeoutException if the query execution exceeds
 * the query timeout value set and only the statement is
 * rolled back
 * @throws TransactionRequiredException if a lock mode has
 * been set and there is no transaction
 * @throws PessimisticLockException if pessimistic locking
 * fails and the transaction is rolled back
 * @throws LockTimeoutException if pessimistic locking
 * fails and only the statement is rolled back
 * @throws PersistenceException if the query execution exceeds
 * the query timeout value set and the transaction
 * is rolled back
 */
X getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It looks like a correct behaviour for me.

`NoResultException` is thrown when no rows are returned, but `sum` returns exactly one row with `null` value in your case. From JPA 2.0 Specification:

> If SUM, AVG, MAX, or MIN is used, and there are no values to which the aggregate function can be
>   applied, the result of the aggregate function is NULL.

If you want to get `0` instead of `null`, use `coalesce`:

```
select coalesce(sum(p.value), 0) ...
```

Comment: I understand that AVG, MAX and MIN of an empty set is undefined, but SUM of an empty set is 0. I wonder why they fail for it.

Comment: SUM, AVG, MAX, or MIN can be 0 for a non-empty set as well. Returning null confirms the empty set.