# How do I return 0 instead of null in postman response?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I made an API which gives me count on basis of location(I used native query in this), this is the method in my service class

```
  public ResponseModel getData(RequestModel mRequestModel) {
            JSONObject mJsonObject = new JSONObject(mRequestModel.getData());
            String startDAte = mJsonObject.getString("StartDate");
    //      String endDate = mJsonObject.getString("EndDate");
            List<ReportModel1> ispeeddetails = ispeedVio.getDataIspeed(startDAte);
            List<ReportModel1> rlvdDetails = rlvdVio.getDataRlvd(startDAte);
            List<ReportModel1> challanDetails = challanRepo.getChallan(startDAte);
            HashMap<String,Webchallanservice> violation = new HashMap<String,Webchallanservice>();
            for(ReportModel1 m:ispeeddetails) {
                String location= m.getLocation();
                if(violation.containsKey(location)) {
                    violation.get(location).setIspped_count(m.getCount());
                }
                else {
                    Webchallanservice challn = new Webchallanservice();
                    challn.setIspped_count(m.getCount());
                    violation.put(location, challn);
                }
            }
if (violation != null && !violation.isEmpty()) {
            return Util.setResponse(AppConstant.SUCCESS_STATUS_CODE, "Successfully Fetched", violation);
        } else {
            return Util.setResponse(AppConstant.ERROR_STATUS_CODE, "No Record Found", violation);

        }
```

The query I used is this

```
@Query(value = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count ,location FROM ispeed_transits v WHERE v.entry_timestamp LIKE %:startDate% GROUP BY v.location", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ReportModel1> getDataIspeed(@Param("startDate") String startDate);
```

The response I am getting on postman is correct but when there is no data its giving me null but I want to return 0.

```
"status": 1,
    "message": "Successfully Fetched",
    "myObjectList": {
        "Taat Mill- From Jhakarkati": {
            "challan_count": 3,
            "ispped_count": null,
            "rlvd_count": 254
        },
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `ispped_count`? Is it `int` or Integer?

Comment: the data type is BigInteger

Comment: How about initialising the value of `ispped_count` to `0` in the constructor of Webchallanservice class itself? Or before returning if-else, you can add `if(violation.get(location).getIspped_count()==null){violation.get(location).setIspped_count(0);}`

Comment: Ok let me try sir

Comment: I tried both ways but 0 cant be initialized in both because, its showing Int value 0 cant be applicable with BigInteger

Comment: Yes because you can't assign an int value to BigInteger directly. Sorry I must have mentioned in the previous comment. You need to use `new BigInteger("0")` instead.

Comment: new BigInteger("0")  in webchallan model or in my service method??

Comment: If you're going for constructor method, then in model but if going for `if`, then in `getData()`, i.e., currently pasted method.

Comment: yes sir I am trying

Comment: if(violation.get(location).getIspped_count()!=null) {
     violation.get(location).setIspped_count(m.getCount());
    }
    else {
     violation.get(location).setIspped_count(new BigInteger("0"));
    }

Comment: its giving same response null

Comment: How can I add this line outside for loop sir as you can see on my code above that location is taken as string inside for loop

Comment: I added this condition after this line if(violation.containsKey(location)

Comment: Ah. I missed that. I assume `count` in `ReportModel1` is also of type BigInteger. Does this help https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Xw4NTyM8jG/?

Comment: yes it is also Biginteger

Comment: See if the above code helps.

Comment: I tried but still giving same response

Comment: Even I tried using bigint to int but still it did not work

Answer (score 0):

axtavt has answered this very eloquently:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10296943/2175570

> `NoResultException` is thrown when no rows are returned, but `sum`
> returns exactly one row with `null` value in your case. From JPA 2.0
> Specification:
>
> > If SUM, AVG, MAX, or MIN is used, and there are no values to which the aggregate function can be applied, the result of the aggregate
> > function is NULL.
>
> If you want to get `0` instead of `null`, use `coalesce`:
>
> ```
> select coalesce(sum(p.value), 0) ...
> ```

Comment: Where I need to use coalesce ?? There are 3 data I am getting on basis of location ispeed_count, rlvd_count, challan_count ,

Comment: I shown you query of ispeed_count rest of the2 queries are same as this one as shown above??

Comment: In response I am getting null if there is no data on that specific data